# Upload Image taken with camera through php to webpage from android with AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, image, android-asynctask, camera

I'm trying to upload an image to a weabpage through a PHP but its the first time so I'm having some difficultys. 
The image that I want to upload should be an image that has been caputed with the camera. 
So, I have one button to captue an Image, and one button to upload (Post), see code.

I now have 2 problems. 
1) The image doesn't get uploaded to the page. 
2) the camera works as it should but after I've used it, the post button, or to take a new picture doesn't work.

See below for MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml and the php.
(I have internet and camera permissions in my manifest)

I would be very grateful if someone should help me!

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

Button Post, TakePic;

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
ImageView imgView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStatea) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStatea);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic);
    Drawable  drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    if (savedInstanceStatea == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Fragment()).commit();  

        TakePic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePic);
        Post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPost);

        TakePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {            
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });             

        Post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new UploadImageTask(imgView).execute();  
            }
        });                     
    }
}       

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);         

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                        
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);          
    }       
}

private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic);

    public UploadImageTask(ImageView imgView) {     
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        //Fetch the image in the image view
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        try {  
        //Create a file to put the bitmap on:
        File f = new File("test.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();          

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file:
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(byteArray);           

          //String fileName = sourceFileUri;          
          HttpURLConnection conns = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";

          //open a URL connection to the Server
          URL url = new URL("http:////ADRESS TO MY PAGE.php");

          //Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
          conns = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
          conns.setDoInput(true);
          conns.setDoOutput(true);
          conns.setUseCaches(false);
          conns.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conns.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          conns.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary); 

          dos = new DataOutputStream(conns.getOutputStream());

          dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
          dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fos + "\"" + lineEnd);                            
          dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);     

          dos.flush();
          dos.close();
          fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return bitmap;          
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic1);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTakePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                android:text="Take picture" />  

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                android:text="POST!" />       

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"            
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_light_holo" />        

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPic1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"            
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_transparent_light_holo" />   

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

php:

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo $file;
}
else {
echo "error";
```

Comment: It is you who has to tell where youre code goes wrong and which errors there are. Now start with clicking the post button. What should happen and what happens instead? Which image are you going to upload?

Comment: When I click the post button I want the picture displayed in the first image view to upload. If I use the camera this one will be the one just captured. If I click post first it will just be at defult image that I added, just for simplicity for now. The second image view will display the same image, also, I use this function just for now to try. The problem is that I dont know the errors, sorry, I'm new on this...

Comment: Don't speak about cameras and other things when clicking the post button as that all is irrelevant at that moment. "Clicking the post button i start an async task, get the image from an imageview and...." (now tell all what you do next. explain the code flow).

Answer (score 0):

PHP upload may not work due to execution time and size of file restriction in PHP Server. So try using FTP upload in android.

Example links:
http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/

http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120

Note: You can do this process in background as well, using AsyncTask.

OR

You can increase the execution time and size for file upload in PHP server as alternative.

Thanks happy coding :)